# Detecting the first row of equal rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

```
ID_NUM           Name Phone TF
24               B       1     False
24               B       2     False
24               B       7     True
38               D       3     False
38               D       4     False
38               D       9     True
```

The value in TF has the following formula (for each row, where ID_NUM is in A column):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1)=1,TRUE,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1))
```

The formula detect the repeating id_num and indicates only the last occurrence.
I would like to change the formula in TF that will indicate as TRUE the first occurrence.

```
The required output will be:
ID_NUM           Name Phone TF
24               B       1     True
24               B       2     False
24               B       7     False
38               D       3     True
38               D       4     False
38               D       9     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with just the last half of your current formula. In D2 as,

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)=1
```

That will be TRUE for unique rows and TRUE for the first occurrence of multiples. Subsequent occurrences will be FALSE.